# Searching analogues of Dash for mac

Tags: software-recommendation

I found [the program](https://kapeli.com/dash) that gives offline access to API documentation sets. But it works on macs only. Do exist same analogues programs for ubuntu? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check [Zeal](https://zealdocs.org), it is an offline documentation browser for software developers.

Here is a screenshot:
[image: Zeal]

Also another option to consider is [DevDocs](http://devdocs.io/), as they say:

> DevDocs combines multiple API documentations in a fast, organized, and
>   searchable interface.

And finally, you can check [DevHelp](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Devhelp):

> Devhelp is a developer tool for browsing and searching API
>   documentation.
>
> It provides an easy way to navigate through libraries and to search by
>   function, struct, or macro.
>
> The documentation must be installed locally, so an internet connection
>   is not needed to use Devhelp.
>
> Devhelp works natively with GTK-Doc, so the GTK+ and GNOME libraries
>   are well supported. But other development platforms can be supported
>   as well, as long as the API documentation is available in HTML and a
>   *.devhelp2 index file is generated (see the README file for more information).
>
> Devhelp integrates with other applications such as Glade, Builder or
>   Anjuta, and plugins are available for different text editors (gedit,
>   Vim, Emacs, Geany, …), see the plugins directory.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you! I installed Zeal, but have two questions.
1. Zeal version is 0.2.0 and Zeal updater ask me for update to 0.5.0. How I can do this.
2. How can I add JSDoc to Zeal?

Comment: To get the latest version of `Zeal` please refer to [this link](https://zealdocs.org/download.html#linux), see the part that says "When the official package becomes outdated, our own PPA repository provides an up-to-date version...". About the 2nd question Docsets are provided by `Dash`, if you want to add a custom Docset you will need a Feed URL, otherwise it is not possible AFAIK.

Comment: I already checked for [JSDoc](http://devdocs.io/jsdoc) in `devdocs` and it is present. You can install it as a [Chrome Extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/devdocs/mnfehgbmkapmjnhcnbodoamcioleeooe?hl=en), hope it helps.

Comment: True that was in bottom of the Zeals website page. So I'm updated. Thanks one more time!